# How should I separate public and private pages on my webserver?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

**What I want to achieve**
I have public and private sites on my webserver, and I would like to somehow separate them, but I want this separation to be invisible.
So for example DocumentRoot is `/var/www` public projects are under `/var/www/public`, private projects are under `/var/www/private`.
If domain is `www.example.com` and I want to reach `public/publicproj1` the URL would be `www.example.com/publicproj1`. Also if I want `private/privateproj1` the URL would be `www.example.com/privateproj1`.
I want to restrict `/var/www/private` only to local network, but `public` should be accessible from anywhere.

Ther are a ton of projects under `private`, I don't want to make new settings in `apache.conf` every time I put something there.

Also I want `/var/www/public/startingpage` to be served if nothing else is requested, so `www.example.com` would show this page.

**What I tried so far:**
1.) made DocumentRoot to `/var/www` put public projects under it and a Rewrite Rule to the `private` folder like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ private/$1 [QSA]
```

This doesn't work, because there are more .htaccess files on the folders under private folder. (for example applications with front controller, forums, etc. which need their own .htaccess)

2.) made DocumentRoot to `/var/www/private`, but then public projects doesn't get served. (Can I make two Document roots with different Access options ?)
I made entries like `Alias /publicproj1 /var/www/publicproj1` but I have Redmine installed with this settings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/$  /redmine  [R]

<Directory /home/www/redmine>
        RailsBaseURI /redmine
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

which I can't replace with a simple `Alias` entry (or can I ?)

**My questions**
What folder structure should I create ? What redirect rules should I make ? How can I set `/var/www/startingpage` to show up when nothing else is requested ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you want to restrict access to `private` projects by IP address, and you have the following directory structure:

> - `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www`
>
>   - public projects are under `/var/www/public`
>   - private projects are under `/var/www/private`

So, in your Apache configuration file (`httpd.conf`) add a `<Directory>` directive like:

```
<Directory /var/www/private>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
</Directory>
```

and everything under that directory will only be accessible if you're coming from the allowed network(s).  (There are [other ways to specify the `Allow`ed hosts too](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow)).

---

> My domain is `www.example.com`.
>   I want to reach `/var/www/html/public/publicproj1` as `www.example.com/publicproj1` and
>   `/var/www/html/private/privateproj1` as `www.example.com/privateproj1`

This is a bit harder.  You're going to need rewrite rules or an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive for each project.  As you noted that's not an ideal situation, so let's look at some other options.

Configured as I described above with the directory structure you have you'll be able to access the directories as `www.example.com/public/proj1` and `www.example.com/private/proj1` out of the box.
If that works for you you're done.

If that's not a good enough solution, consider moving your public projects so they're directly under `/var/www/html` -- your public projects would then be accessible as `www.example.com/publicproj1`, and your private projects would be accessible with the `/private/` bit added in. (Presumably you don't care so much about a little ugly in the URL of a "private" project, and this avoids the need to do any `Alias`ing for your public stuff).

---

Regarding the starting page, you can show content of `startingpage` folder if `www.example.com` is requested with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/startingpage/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /startingpage/$1
```

Comment: good answer, but I did this too and I don't want to have `/private/` in the URL.Could you tell me what rewrite rules should I use to redirect everything what is in private but not in root ?

Comment: @Walkman not specifically, because the rewrite rule would be particular to your environment.  However you may find [Everything you ever wanted to know about mod_rewrite rules but were afraid to ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) helpful...

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you restrict those folders using .htaccess password protecting method?

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/password-protect-your-webpages-using-htaccess/

Comment: did you read my question ? I don't want to deal with passwords. I want to restrict based on IP address...